# Big size when compiling the code using packages like numpy and wxpython

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, wxpython

I have write a code which has size only 2x kb and uses the numpy and wxpython package.

Then I compiled it successfully using Pyinstaller; however, its executable size is almost 300mb.

I think the reason that the executable is so big is that the Pyinstaller includes all the files in numpy. But actually I didn't use all the function in numpy. Pyinstaller is not smart enough to only include those files that I have used but also include those that I haven't used.

Is there any way for me to shrink the size of my executable?

Comment: Don't know why pyinstaller would include that much.I use wxPython, matplotlib, numpy and some other stuff like sqlalchemy, firebird SQL, amara XML and some other stuff and get a distribution folder of about 35 MB, but I use py2exe.

Comment: Last update of py2exe seems to be long time ago. It seems not to support numpy well as I remember I got many error when I used it to compile a code using numpy.

Comment: py2exe is maintained by Thomas Heller and just recently he issued a version compatible with Python 3.  I have no special code in setup.py for numpy but maybe that is because only use it for the limited stuff I do with matplotlib.

Comment: As @werner mentioned ``py2exe``, the same is true for ``PyInstaller`` on Windows. I have here wxPython 2.9.5 and numpy 1.8.0 and got 20 - 30 MB in the dist dir. You could check first in the package source directories if there is something unexpected (size-wise) there. Furthermore there is [PyInstaller ArchiveViewer](http://www.pyinstaller.org/export/develop/project/doc/Manual.html#id14), if you need to inspect what got packed into the exe.

Comment: Do you mean `PyInstaller` can compile code with the packages wxPython and numpy to an executable in a manageable size as long as I exclude some packages? Any Example?

Comment: If you are on Windows 32 bit (which I have here) on a python installation out of the box and use PyInstaller on a python script which uses wx and numpy, the resulting dist folder will contain around 30 MB (zipped up it is below 15 MB). As far as I know, there is no "compile" optimization when freezing; if for example you import numpy in your frozen app the frozen numpy part will always be the same, no matter if your app uses every single function in the package or you merely do `import <package>`. Just try it out.

Comment: Hand-optimizing by explicitely excluding packages will work, but is in my opinion only useful and doable, if you *exactly* know if you will need the excluded part or not.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem on Windows 10 using Anaconda. My simple Numpy + wxPython application was resulting in a 700MB distribution from PyInstaller.

The reason for the bloat seemed to be the Intel Math Kernel Libraries (MKL) that my version of Numpy was using. The dist output directory contained a number of very large mkl-* files.

Since my application doesn't require the optimized math libraries for performance, I was able to shrink my PyInstaller output to 102MB (from 700MB) by using a version of Numpy without MKL.

Here's what I did:

1. Installed Python from python.org
2. Installed required packages with pip, including a version of numpy that doesn't use the Intel MKL.

   ```
   python -mpip install numpy
   python -mpip install setuptools
   python -mpip install python-dateutil
   python -mpip install pytz
   python -mpip install pyparsing
   python -mpip install cycler
   python -mpip install matplotlib
   python -mpip install wxpython
   python -mpip install pandas
   python -mpip install pyinstaller
   python -mpip install pywin32-ctypes
   ```
3. Built it with

   ```
   python -mPyInstaller app.py
   ```

Here is the resulting numpy configuration (note the last 4 lines where it says lapack_mkl_info and blas_mkl_info is not available):

```
C:\Python27>c:\Python27\python.exe
Python 2.7.14 (v2.7.14:84471935ed, Sep 16 2017, 20:25:58) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.show_config()
lapack_opt_info:
    libraries = ['libopenblas_v0.2.20_mingwpy', 
'libopenblas_v0.2.20_mingwpy']
    library_dirs = ['c:\\opt\\64\\lib']
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    language = c
blas_opt_info:
    libraries = ['libopenblas_v0.2.20_mingwpy', 
'libopenblas_v0.2.20_mingwpy']
    library_dirs = ['c:\\opt\\64\\lib']
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    language = c
openblas_info:
    libraries = ['libopenblas_v0.2.20_mingwpy', 
'libopenblas_v0.2.20_mingwpy']
    library_dirs = ['c:\\opt\\64\\lib']
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    language = c
blis_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
openblas_lapack_info:
    libraries = ['libopenblas_v0.2.20_mingwpy', 
'libopenblas_v0.2.20_mingwpy']
    library_dirs = ['c:\\opt\\64\\lib']
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    language = c
lapack_mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
blas_mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
```

Comment: Does `pip install numpy` not install numpy _with_ MKL dependencies by default?

Comment: @normanius, after installing Python 2.7.14 64-bit from python.org on my Windows 10 computer, and following the above steps, I did not end up with MKL dependencies.